# utPLSQL Testing htp.p

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, plsql

Is it possible to unit test (utPLSQL) a procedure that is used only for generating html/javascript? (via htp.p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For unit testing and debugging PL/SQL procedures you can use the latest version of SQL Developer . 
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15846_01/doc.21/e15222/unit_testing.htm

Comment: So SQL Developer has some kind of mechanism to grab information from the htp buffer for unit testing?

Comment: Thanks for the link though, it's pretty interesting. I've always used toad. I might have to check out SQL Developer.

Comment: I switched from TOAD to SQL Developer years ago. TOAD is much bigger, it tries to be everything to everybody (Developers and DBA's). SQL Developer is more targetted at developers, and that's what I use it for. And it's free.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but I want to close this question.